# How to use execl as replacement for system

Tags: c++, execl

```
int main(void)
{
    execl("echo", "test");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to execute command echo test with `execl` 
Why ? Because i can't use `system()` i have some reasons 
What is wrong ?

Comment: Don't know what is wrong, sorry, but have you checked out the man pages for `execl` for usage information?

Comment: You need to read the manual really carefully to figure out which of the `execxxx` functions is best suited to your needs and what parameters they accept. You may prefer `execlp` like: `execlp("echo", "echo", "test", nullptr);`. That checks the system `PATH` to find the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `execl` function does not look up commands on your PATH like a shell would, so you need to provide the full path to `echo` (or else provide a relative path from your current working directory, I think).  Also, the first arg in the args list should be the filename of the executable, and the last arg should be `NULL` so that execl can figure out how many args you are trying to pass.

This works for me:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    execl("/bin/echo", "/bin/echo", "test", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

You can run `which echo` to find out where `echo` is located on your system; it might be different from mine and you would have to edit the code.